# What is the default setting for a digital output pin

Tags: arduino-uno

With `digitalWrite(pin_number,value)`, we can set an output pin as `HIGH` or `LOW`. But if only coding `pinMode (pin_number, OUTPUT)`, what is the default state for the pin `pin_number`, `LOW` or `HIGH`? It is noted that: `Pins configured as OUTPUT with pinMode() are said to be in a low-impedance state`. Does that mean the pin will be in the state `LOW`?

Comment: neither, they are HI-Z ... all pins are set as input with pullup resistors disabled ... that means that they are seen as floating (disconnected) ... any pin that has an external pullup or pulldown resistor will be pulled in the direction of the resistor

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On the AVR-based Arduinos at least, pins start in the `INPUT`, i.e. high
impedance state. If you then `pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);`, the pin turns to
`OUTPUT` `LOW`. Note, however, that if you first set the pin to
`INPUT_PULLUP`, and **then** to `OUTPUT`, the pin ends up in the
`OPUTPUT` `HIGH` state.

Sometimes you want to control the state the pin will have right when
it's turned to `OUTPUT`. You may for example simulate an open collector
output by switching between `INPUT` (or `INPUT_PULLUP`) and `OUTPUT`
`LOW`, while avoiding the `OUTPUT` `HIGH` state. In this case, a safe
idiom is to set the output level *before* switching the pin to `OUTPUT`,
e.g.

```cpp
// Set pin to OUTPUT LOW without going throught the OUTPUT HIGH state.
digitalWrite(pin, LOW); // do this first
pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
```

A side effect of performing a `digitalWrite()` on a pin that is not set
to `OUTPUT` is that the pin gets switched to either `INPUT` (if writing
`LOW`) or `INPUT_PULLUP` (if writing `HIGH`). This is an idiosyncrasy of
the AVR IO ports you should probably not rely on if you want your code
to be readable or portable.

Reference: [the source code of `pinMode()`](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/1.6.23/cores/arduino/wiring_digital.c#L29) in the Arduino
core, and the datasheet of the relevant MCU. See for example the section
[Ports as General Digital I/O](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega48A-PA-88A-PA-168A-PA-328-P-DS-DS40002061A.pdf#G3.1185755) in the ATmega328P’s datasheet.

Answer (score 6):

I've had a similar issue with an ATTINY85 powered DIGISPARK board.

I was getting a glitch when setting a pin to `OUTPUT` and the driving it `HIGH` immediately. Looked something like this:

`CH1:`

`pinMode(ch1, OUTPUT);          // it is at this line that ch1 becomes LOW`

`digitalWrite(ch1, LOW);        // technically redundant since ch1 pin already driven LOW`

`CH2:`

`pinMode(ch2, OUTPUT);          // at this point ch2 goes LOW`

`digitalWrite(ch2, HIGH);       // and only goes HIGH once this instruction executes`

[image: Glitch on CH2 when setting PIN to OUTPUT and then turning it HIGH]

The solution that mitigated the above glitch in my case (ATTiny85 / Digispark Board) was, as Edgar Bonet pointed out above, going through the INPUT_PULLUP phase:

`pinMode(ch2, INPUT_PULLUP);`

`pinMode(ch2, OUTPUT);`

`digitalWrite(ch2, HIGH);`